# Problems when a json string has extra " in it using JObject.Parse

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

The Following string gives an error when using the following code:

```
 data = await resposta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 dynamic j = JObject.Parse(data);
```

The data in contains the following string:

```
{"code": 100, "message": "The entity with the name "Esther Rea" its not in DB."}
```

How to take off the " from Esther Rea?

Comment: Is there any chance you could get the web service or site to fix the invalid JSON they are sending you?  According to the [original proposal](http://www.json.org/) and the [standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-7): *All Unicode characters may be placed within the quotation marks, except for the characters that **must be escaped: quotation mark**, reverse solidus, and the control characters...*  so it's clearly a bug on the sending side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, the correct solution would be to have whoever's returning this value escape the quotes. However, if that's really not an option, you can try to brute-force your way into escaping the double quotes yourself, assuming the return schema is always the same, using something like this:

```
var pattern = "(\"message\":\\s+\")(?<messageContent>(.*))(\"})";
var regex = Regex.Match(data, pattern);

var message = regex.Groups["messageContent"].Value;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
{
    message = message.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
    var newData = Regex.Replace(data, pattern, "$1" + message + "$3");

    var jObject = JObject.Parse(newData);
}
```

This will extract the actual `message` string and escapes all double quotes in it (`message.Replace("\"", "\\\"");`), causing serialization to succeed.

If you really want to remove the quotes instead of escaping them, you can do `message = message.Replace("\"", "");`

Comment: That solution was implemented with sucess and it works fine thanks